# How to save One-to-Many Relationship in CoreData?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, sqlite, one-to-many

I have one tables looks like as below

[image: RelationShip]

[image: CLUBDETAILS]

[image: CLUBDETAILSIMAGES]

I have one XML where detail of ***CLUB*** is available. Every tag has one value but Images tag contain dynamic images.

After this my object looks like as below

***ClubDetails.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "ClubDetailsImages.h"



@interface ClubDetails : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubarea;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubdealhere;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubdescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubdistance;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubemail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubfacility;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubfav;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clublat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clublogopath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubphone;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * cluburl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clubvenutype;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * clublong;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *clubdetailsimages;
@end

@interface ClubDetails (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addClubdetailsimagesObject:(ClubDetailsImages *)value;
- (void)removeClubdetailsimagesObject:(ClubDetailsImages *)value;
- (void)addClubdetailsimages:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeClubdetailsimages:(NSSet *)value;
```

Its ***.m*** files looks like as below

```
@implementation ClubDetails

@dynamic clubarea;
@dynamic clubdealhere;
@dynamic clubdescription;
@dynamic clubdistance;
@dynamic clubemail;
@dynamic clubfacility;
@dynamic clubfav;
@dynamic clubid;
@dynamic clublat;
@dynamic clublogopath;
@dynamic clubname;
@dynamic clubphone;
@dynamic cluburl;
@dynamic clubvenutype;
@dynamic clublong;
@dynamic clubdetailsimages;


    - (void)addClubdetailsimagesObject:(ClubDetailsImages *)value {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages"] addObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    }

    - (void)removeClubdetailsimagesObject:(ClubDetailsImages *)value {
        NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages"] removeObject:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    }

    - (void)addClubdetailsimages:(NSSet *)value {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages"] unionSet:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    }

    - (void)removeClubdetailsimages:(NSSet *)value {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
        [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages"] minusSet:value];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"ClubDetailsImages" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    }


***ClubDetailsImages.h*** looks like

    @class ClubDetails;

    @interface ClubDetailsImages : NSManagedObject

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * images;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) ClubDetails *clubdetailed;


***ClubDetailsImages.m*** looks like

    @implementation ClubDetailsImages

    @dynamic images;
    @dynamic clubdetailed;



For Saving, I wrote code like this



-(void)saveClubDetails:(NSMutableArray*)allClubs{


    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ClubDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context]];

    [fetchRequest setIncludesPropertyValues:NO]; //only fetch the managedObjectID

    NSArray *allObject = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (NSManagedObject * obj in allObject) {
        [context deleteObject:obj];
    }
    NSError *saveError = nil;
    [context save:&saveError]; // NO MORE VALUE IS DB



    for (int x = 0; x<[allClubs count]; x++) {

        ClubDetails *club = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClubDetails"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:context];


        ClubDetails2 *ob = (ClubDetails2*)[allClubs objectAtIndex:x];

        club.clubarea = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubarea];
        club.clubdealhere = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubdealhere];
        club.clubdescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubdescription];
        club.clubdistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubdistance];
        club.clubemail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubemail];
        club.clubfacility = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubfacility];
        club.clubfav = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubfav];

        club.clubid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubid];
        club.clublat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clublat];
        club.clublogopath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clublogopath];
        club.clubname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubname];
        club.clubphone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubphone];
        club.cluburl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.cluburl];

        club.clubvenutype = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clubvenutype];
        club.clublong = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ob.clublong];


        ClubDetailsImages *clubImages = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClubDetailsImages"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];


        clubImages.images = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"veer url image"];
        [club addClubdetailsimagesObject:clubImages];

    }

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }


    //  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Clubs"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *fetchedArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSLog(@"COUNT of arary is %d", [fetchedArray count]);


    for (Clubs *info in fetchedArray) {
        NSLog(@" Duaan Name  ~~~~ : %@", info.clubname);
    }


}
```

I AM STUCK IN FOLLOWING POINTS

***1. How to save such objects in CoreData where one club may be 3, 4, 5 images which are stored in Array?***

***2. How can I fetch that one-to-more relationship from CoreData?***

Comment: Not sure what the problem is? you are only adding one image to the `ClubDetailsImages` object (manually). to add more iterate over received data and create `ClubDetailsImages` objects as needed. fetching should be as simple as accessing the relationship and iterating the set.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just keep adding the objects and linking them to the ClubDetails, e.g.given that you have an array of image strings from somewhere....

   ```
   for (NSString *image in images)
   {
       ClubDetailsImages *clubImages = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClubDetailsImages" inManagedObjectContext:context];

       clubDetailsImages.image = image;
       clubDetailsImages.clubdetailed = club;
   }
   ```
2. Not sure exactly what you asking here, but given a ClubDetails instance:

   ```
   NSSet *images = club.clubdetailsimages;
   ```

Also, why have you implemented addClubdetailsimagesObject etc.  This is not required.  Use XCode to generate your entity classes and you will see that these methods are not created.

Comment: So if you doesn't have to implement the methods addClubdetailsimagesObject etc. who does implements them? and how? What does it happened when I call those methods?